# SQL group by returns wrong data

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

This is making me crazy! Musing MySQL DBMS (sorry not for specifying that)...

I have following table:

```
"id", "pingdate", "players"
"3","2012-05-24 11:45:04","63"
"1","2012-05-24 12:15:03","14"
"2","2012-05-24 12:15:03","38"
"3","2012-05-24 12:15:03","24"
"1","2012-05-24 12:45:04","22"
"2","2012-05-24 12:45:04","40"
"3","2012-05-24 12:45:04","66"
"1","2012-05-24 13:15:03","14"
"5","2012-05-24 13:15:03","99"
"3","2012-05-24 13:15:03","63"
"3","2012-05-24 13:15:03","38"
"4","2012-05-24 13:15:03","63"
```

I want following result:

```
"5","2012-05-24 13:15:03","99"
"3","2012-05-24 12:45:04","66"
"4","2012-05-24 13:15:03","63"
```

In text, i want 3 diffent ID´s, with highest players and the correct pingdate.

I have tried this, but it returns the wrong pingdate:

```
SELECT id, 
       pingdate, 
       max(players) AS players 
FROM pings 
GROUP BY id  
ORDER BY players DESC 
LIMIT 3
```

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by the "correct pingdate".  Elaborate.

Comment: He means he wants the pingdate for the row with the highest players value

Comment: BTW: in your example there is no result row for id=2. Oops that's the stupid LIMIT.

Comment: Is this a MySQL question, I say that because of the LIMIT keyword?

Comment: Yes it's MySQL, sorry for not specifying that. Sorry if the question is a bit hard to understand :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to do it with a join or subquery, see [sql - getting the id from a row based on a group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588095/sql-getting-the-id-from-a-row-based-on-a-group-by)

```
Select  a.id, a.pingdate, a.players from pings a, (
  SELECT id, max(players) AS players 
  FROM pings 
  GROUP BY id ) b 
where a.id=b.id and a.players=b.players 
ORDER BY players DESC 
LIMIT 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify a DBMS, so this is an ANSI SQL solution:

```
select *
from (
    select id, 
           pingdate,
           rank() over (partition by id order by players desc) as rnk
    from pings
) t
where rnk <= 3
order by players desc
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to return all results....and then return just 3

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT id,pingdate, max(players) AS players 
FROM pings 
GROUP BY id, pingdate  )
WHERE rownum = 3
ORDER BY players DESC
```

i hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

The definition of maximal := there is no higher value:

```
SELECT id, pingdate, players 
FROM pings pi
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT *
         FROM pings nx
         WHERE nx.id = pi.id
         AND nx.players > pi.players
         )
ORDER BY players
LIMIT 3
    ;
```